# How to identify different protein domains using HHpred

Tags: proteins, protein-structure, structural-biology

I am new to HHpred/ analyzing proteins so bare with me. I have been given an uncharacterized protein, whose FASTA sequence I have obtained from Uniprot. I am looking to do the following by using HHpred.

So far, I have done the following:

- obtained FASTA sequence and inputted it into HHpred.
- Loaded the FASTA sequence on to HHpred.

What I am looking to do on HHpred now:

- Identify the different domains/motifs of this uncharacterized protein
- Compare full length protein to two separate domains
- Determine if the predictions has improved by comparing the full length proteins to the separate domains.

All comments help, I am very desperate for any tips.

Thank you!

Comment: Do the automated annotation databases, such as PFam etc., in the Uniprot section Family & Domain, have anything annotated? Are they missing the domain you are after (they generally do), is the boundary wrong (they generally are), do you want more granularity (family too big) _etc_, _etc_?